# Javascript Select option in Select box based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that contains many classes. If the the div is clicked on and one of it's classes matches the value any option in the select box, i want that option to be selected.

```
<div class="abc cdf fff r10 yyy">
<select id="whatever">
    <option value="r10">test10</option>
    <option value="r20">test20</option>
    <option value="r30">test30</option>
</select>
```

How do i achieve this with JavaScript or jQuery
I tried the following but can't get it to work.

```
var roundclasses = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s/); //This outputs the array of classes sucessfully
for (var i in roundclasses){
    $('#whatever').val(roundclasses[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your implementation is not working, because if you try setting `val()` with non-existing value, then the select will get reset to 1st option. So for example `$('#whatever').val('r30');` will set 3rd option, but then calling `$('#whatever').val('yyy');` will reset the select to 1st option.

Comment: @dzejkej Thanks, i realized that now. Is there a way to tell it to stop if a value is found rather then continuing and resetting

Comment: I'm not aware of any simple method. But I created a shorter solution than my previous one in case you are interested. See my answer or [directly this](http://jsbin.com/editib/5/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Here**](http://jsbin.com/editib/2/edit) is the JSBin snippet.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="clickDiv" class="abc cdf fff r30 yyy">
  <p>CLICK</p>
</div>
<select id="whatever">
  <option value="r10">test10</option>
  <option value="r20">test20</option>
  <option value="r30">test30</option>
</select>
```

**JS (using jQuery):**

```
var div = $("#clickDiv");
var sel =  $("#whatever");
var options = $("#whatever option");
div.click(function() {
  options.each(function(index, e) {
    if (div.hasClass(e.value)) {
      sel.val(e.value);
    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Created a JSBin with shorter solution - [**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/editib/5/edit)

```
var div = $("#clickDiv");
var options = $("#whatever option");
div.click(function() {
  options.attr('selected', function() {
    return div.hasClass(this.value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jVtdf/)**.

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="clickme" class="abc cdf fff r10 yyy">Click Me</div>

<br>
<br>

<select multiple="true" id="dd">
    <option value="r1">test1 (r1)</option>
    <option value="r2">test2 (r2)</option>
    <option value="r2">test3 (cdf)</option>
    <option value="yyy">test4 (yyy)</option>
    <option value="r10">test9 (r10)</option>
    <option value="r10">test10 (r10)</option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
#clickme {
    background: #FF0000;
    color: #FFF;
    font: 14px Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var $dd = $("#dd"),
    $dd_opts = $dd.find('option');

$("#clickme").click(function() {
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' '),
        class_len = classes.length;

    $dd.val('');

    for (x = 0, class_len = classes.length; x < class_len; x++) {
        var cls = classes[x],
            $opts = $dd_opts.filter('[value="'+ cls +'"]');

        $opts.attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't want this for multiple select. Just a regular select as per my question. Anyway +1 for showing this way.